# React Native - do changes to build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml get updated with fast refresh?

Tags: android, react-native

Or do these updates require a `./gradle clean build` uninstall/reinstall or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, changes to native code will always require a rebuild. Towards the end of the Native Modules tutorial is this:

`The final step is to rebuild the React Native app so that you can have the latest native code (with your new native module!) available.`

Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#test-what-you-have-built

Answer (score 1):

Fast refresh works only for javascript changes not for internal files of android and iOS. You need to build the app again.